# Why does this insertion sort unable to sort arrays of objects? (but can other values)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I've made this insertion sort algorithm, and it works fine with numbers/strings if you remove the `.name`'s in the second loop. Though I can't get it to work with an array of object? (I've even tried a few desk checks and I still can't figure out the problem...)

```
function insertSortByName(d) {
    const len = d.length - 1;
    let output = d;

    for(let sorted = len; sorted >= 0; sorted--) {

        for(let key = sorted-1; output[key].name > output[key+1].name; key++) {
            output = swapArrayVal(output, key, key+1);
        }

    }

    return output;
}

function swapArrayVal(arr, pos1, pos2) {
    let tempVal = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = tempVal;
    return arr;
}
```

This would be could be run with an example array as such:

```
insertSortByName([ {name: 'z'}, {name: 'm'}, {name: 'a'} ]);
/* Should return: [ {name: 'a'}, {name: 'm'}, {name: 'z'}] */
```

Comment: You are reading past the end of array. You're missing stop condition in your inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
for(let key = sorted-1; output[key].name > output[key+1].name; key++) {
```

Change  it to:

```
for(let key=sorted-1; !!output[key+1] && !!output[key] &&
                            output[key].name>output[key+1].name; key++) {
```

```js
function insertSortByName(d) {
    const len = d.length - 1;
    let output = d;

    for(let sorted = len; sorted >= 0; sorted--) {

        for(let key = sorted-1; !!output[key+1] && !!output[key] && output[key].name > output[key+1].name; key++) {
            output = swapArrayVal(output, key, key+1);
        }

    }

    return output;
}

function swapArrayVal(arr, pos1, pos2) {
    let tempVal = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = tempVal;
    return arr;
}
var retVal = insertSortByName([ {name: 'z'}, {name: 'm'}, {name: 'a'} ]);

console.log(retVal);
```

A different implementation can be based on the algorithm available on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

```
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

In the following snippet i changed while with for, right to create something similar to your approach:

```js
function insertSortByName(arr) {
    for(var i=1; i<arr.length;) {
        for(var j=i; j>0 && arr[j-1].name > arr[j].name;) {
            var tempVal = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = tempVal;
            j -= 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    return arr;
}
var retVal = insertSortByName([ {name: 'z'}, {name: 'm'}, {name: 'a'} ]);

console.log(retVal);
```

The previous code can be improved adding a compare callback like for the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).  In this way you can continue to use the same function for different objects.

```js
function insertSort(arr, compareCallBack) {
    for(var i=1; i<arr.length;) {
        for(var j=i; j>0 && compareCallBack(arr[j-1], arr[j]);) {
            var tempVal = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = tempVal;
            j -= 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    return arr;
}
var retVal = insertSort([ {name: 'z'}, {name: 'm'}, {name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'} ], (a, b) => {return a.name > b.name;});

console.log('insertSort with objects: ' + JSON.stringify(retVal));


retVal = insertSort([ 'z', 'm', 'a', 'b'], (a, b) => {return a.localeCompare(b) > 0;});

console.log('insertSort with letters: ' + retVal);

retVal = insertSort([ 10, 7, 8, 1 ], (a, b) => {return a > b;});

console.log('insertSort with numbers: ' + retVal);
```

Comment: This works, although I would personally recommend doing proper bounds checking instead of creating an escape hatch for the use of invalid indexes.

Comment: Alright, I've tried properly setting bounds with `(key <= len-1) && (output[key].name > output[key+1].name)` (brackets purely visual, split 2 checks up in my head). Though, because of `&&`, I guess it still runs `.name` on output so throws undefined. This `key <= len-1` could be wrong, though, if you don't mind, could you share how you'd enforce boundaries in this case.